# Striding a 2D model over an image to produce image of labels (NOT convolution)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I have a model trained from RGB image samples that take a 31x31 pixel region as input and produces a single classification for the center pixel.

I'd like to apply this model over an entire image to recover effectively a new image of classifications for each pixel. Since this isn't a convolution, I'm not sure what the preferred way to do this is in TensorFlow.

I know this is possible by exploding the image for inference into a ton of smaller tensors but this seems like a colossal waste since each pixel will be duplicated 961 times. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Wait what? Why is this getting down votes did anyone actually read the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your model a `fully-convolutional`  neural network, so for a `31x31` image it will produce a `single label` and for a `62x62` image it will produce `2x2` labels and so on. This will remove the redundant computation you talked about in case of windowing method.

If in case the network has a fully-connected layer, it can be replaced with  a convolutional ones using a `1x1` kernel.

Comment: FYI I think you meant 32x32 image to get a 2x2 output with a 31x31 window.